# Copying Text using ClipBoard_SetData() doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm calling a function to copy text to the Windows clipboard using the API function from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210216 using Access 2003 on Windows XP.

The function does clear the Clipboard, but it silently fails on the actual assignment to the clipboard. Stepping through the code and querying for errors in the immediate window yields nothing.

I copied and pasted the MS function exactly as shown on their webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function, which does almost exactly the same thing. It uses the Registry Key to the Clipboard. Try it out.

```
Public Sub CopyTextToClipboard(ByVal inText As String)
'***************************************
'       Background copy of any Text
'***************************************
    Dim objClipboard As Object
    Set objClipboard = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    objClipboard.SetText inText
    objClipboard.PutInClipboard

    Set objClipboard = Nothing
End Sub
```

So to copy any test you simply use,

```
CopyTextToClipboard "Hello World !!"
```

Then use **Ctrl+V** to paste it.

Comment: I hate work-arounds, I'd like to know why the MSDN code doesn't work. But your code works, so I quess I'll forget the "why" and "git er dun" instead. Thanks!